# SQL returned by Wp_Query has wp_posts.ID = -1

Tags: wp-query

I have a custom loop based on these arguments (below), and for some reason when it's run, the SQL returned has this fragment:

... AND wp_posts.ID = -1 ...

And I get no results from the db. If I run the query against the db without this fragment, I get the results I need. Could someone, please, point out what's wrong with argument list that causes this behavior?

```
$args = array (
    'post_status'           => 'draft',
    'posts_per_page'        => 10,
    'category_name'         => $language_sql_param, //fixed
    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'review_rating',
            'value'     => '3',
            'compare'   => '>',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
    'cache_results'          => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'meta_key' => 'review_id',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
); 

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

## Revised question:

I am filtering posts based on a category(s) they belong too, in my case they are country codes. Here's the SQL that WP generates when I set `$language_sql_param` to this:

```
$language_sql_param = 'us,gb,ca,au,ie'
```

It works fine and returns IDs for my posts for EN speaking countries.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
        AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (20,21,28,36,37) )
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
        AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'draft')
        AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'review_id'
        AND (mt1.meta_key = 'review_rating'
        AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '3') )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

When I set `$language_sql_param = "'de,ch'"`, I get this SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
        AND wp_posts.ID = -1
        AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (27,34) )
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
        AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'draft')
        AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'review_id'
        AND (mt1.meta_key = 'review_rating'
        AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '3') )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The SQL has this extra `AND wp_posts.ID = -1`. WordPress seems to correctly generate the IN clause for the categories I am filtering, as in `AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (27,34))`, but because WordPress somehow adds `AND wp_posts.ID = -1` condition no posts are returned.

Where is `AND wp_posts.ID = -1` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Syntax highlighting editor, you may be able to spot these problems easier.

Change this code:

```
'category_name'         => ",
```

To this code:

```
'category_name'         => '',
```

That will fix the syntax error in your code.

Comment: I accidently deleted the param for 'category_name'

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Does this correction fix the problem you are having?

Comment: Hi Charles, I've updated my original question. This doesn't fix it, but only because I didn't post my issue properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You say that it works fine with

> `$language_sql_param = 'us,gb,ca,au,ie'`

but that it breaks with

> `$language_sql_param = "'de,ch'"`

Does it work with `$language_sql_param = 'de,ch'`?

#### Rationale:

`'us,gb,ca,au,ie'` != `"'us,gb,ca,ie'"`.  In the latter case, you've got extra `'` characters in the string you're passing for the `$language_sql_param`.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to make an difference. The IN clause gets constructed correctly, as in AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (27,34)). It's that extra AND wp_posts.ID = -1 that's throwing things off.